# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' Permission denied

Tags: iis, asp-classic, file-permissions

I get the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' Permission denied

When running a classic asp application.

The error is here: (in the `CreateTextFile` line)

```
Dim myFSO
set myFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
myFSO.CreateTextFile(fName)
```

I know I can get around this problem by giving "Full control" to the "Everyone" user. This is a publicly accessible folder on our server, so I worry that this is a security risk?

I would prefer to be able to give full permission to someone like "IIS_IUSRS", but this doesn't work. It's as if it's a different user being used for this.

Is this a security risk? Anyone know what I should be doing?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you running this application and which O/S? (e.g. IIS7 on Windows Server 2003). You can set read/write permissions for `IUSR_<SERVER_NAME>` and `IWAM_<SERVER_NAME>`. You might also need to set it for the `IIS_WPG` user.

Comment: Permissions can get really tricky. Why not taking a different direction, for example create those files in a "sandbox" location somewhere under the website root then have external application that will monitor that location and copy "valid" files to the shared folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should either find the anonymous user of your specific website and give write access to that specific user or set the application pool identity of the website to Local System so that the website would have permission.

To find your IUSR also known as the anonymous user in IIS7, open your website in IIS in Features View and go to Authentication and edit Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: Same applies to IIS8.5. Slightly more detailed instructions here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20911145/55041 but also had to make sure read permissions for IIS_IUSRS was set on the folders.