# Simple file writing error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I've got a larger project that is not writing to a file on the server - so I just made a script that was bare bones testing. It as well won't write to the file..

```
<%
Dim objFSO, objTS

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("d:\Webs\mwstim0080\ch\Cashier\brant_guest_cash_completed.txt", 8, true)
objTS.Write "brant"

objTS.Close
Set objTS = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied

/ch/Cashier/brant.asp, line 5
```

Server is Win box with IIS 6.0.. Help?

Comment: does the app pool have access to that file?

Comment: Excellent question... Being as I'm trying to handle this for a client and I've never messed with ASP, I'll have to research how to a) check that and b) give the app pool access.

Comment: I rarely do web - but what I'm used to is PHP which doesn't require APP POOL access (that I'm aware of)

Comment: It did not apparently...... ARGH!!!

Comment: It happens to the best of us

Comment: I have to claim ignorance on it as I was unaware of the App Pool concept in conjunction with ASP.. Thank you sir.. If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'll upvote and check you off.

Comment: Ithink this is a same problem try this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893030/microsoft-vbscript-runtime-error-800a0046-permission-denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that your IIS application pool has permission to that file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

Second option  would be create tmp folder within root directory of your application/website. That will ensure that you do not need to mess with system and users permissions.
All what you will need is to create folder within site structure and get path to it which is simple enough in VBScript.